# How to dynamically remove all unwanted CSS and JS from page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an amateur sports website to maintain and I am not an expert in web development. The pages I can put on the website can only be in the form of predefined templates, something similar to wordpress.

The main website loads it's own CSS files and JS files which we do not want as it interferes with our customisations. These files change as and when the main administrators/developers deploy new ones to the main/parent website.

I want to dynamically block loading of all CSS files and JS files that are not ours and instead use our own custom CSS and JS files.

Currently I am doing something like this below, but as you can see I will have to update the file names whenever they change to something else and I would not know when they change unless I notice the difference on the webpages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('link[rel=stylesheet][href="/assets/application-b51e2731e0d53e4d422.css"]').remove();
  $('link[rel=stylesheet][href="/assets/print-a622ffc90d1232b126e42c.css"]').remove();
  jQuery('head script[src*="application-7fd426f9bca208.js"]').remove();
</script>
```

Is there a better way to block all unwanted css / js files dynamically without me having to hardcode it like I have done above?

Comment: Possibly write a php function - depends on your framework i guess?

Comment: I can only upload html which can contain scripts in it.

Comment: It's extra overhead but depending on your limitations you can add a CSS reset **after** their files are loaded. [Example](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: I am not allowed to administer the website, only allowed to update webpages with new html.

Comment: Ok then a CSS reset may be your only option. Not sure what to do about the JS though.

Comment: Check this out. It might help you: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml

Comment: First of all, removing `script` tags won't prevent them from running.

Comment: @Ginden If his script ran first, with commands to remove other scripts...how would they still run?

Comment: @slime scripts are loaded and run just as soon as the `<script>` tag is seen.   By definition, if the script exists (such that it could be removed) it must already have been loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of worrying about tracking file names, why not just target anything that's not yours?

```
$('link').not('.myLink').remove();
```

And just make sure you drop that class on your `link`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path.css" class="myLink" />
```

Comment: this works fine. Any suggestions to remove .js file?

Comment: Apparently it's not possible to unload JS from browser memory. If their JS is conflicting with yours, then you could just namespace your code, but if their JS is affecting your CSS, then you're gonna have to write JS to nullify the values/functions/whatever found in their JS.